# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. - getting this error in db url

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

This is my string

```
 const uri = 'mongodb+srv://ad:xyz@abc-2xyzs.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

 const client = new MongoClient(uri);
```

I'm getting the error

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
.
.
.
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

I have tried to parse url. But nothing seems to be working

Comment: Is this the exact context of the code? Because it's definitely not undefined after immediate declaration

Comment: I have this same issue. I tried updating Express, but no dice. Just as minimal as this results in the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated my socket.io and express version and this error was resolved

Answer (score -1):

You have to upgrade your dependencies. Run npm update --save

Comment: Please study and use this information https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help